# Java based icon movement

Tags: java, game-physics

I have the following code which moves an icon around the perimeter of box in a java application screen starting by moving up the screen 19 times  then turning right until it gets back to on step before its original starting place -

```
public class MyClass {
public static void moveNTimes(MyObject main, int numberOfMoves) { 
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfMoves; i++) { 
    main.move(); 

    } 
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyObject main = new MyObject();


   for (int i = 19; i >=0; i--){
       moveNTimes(main, i);
   main.turnRight(); 

   i = i + 1;


       }
   }
}
```

My problem being when it has got to the end of the perimeter of the box I need it to turn into the next line, which would have 18 place to moves around the next perimeter, then seventeen etc until the icon has finished in the center of the screen.

Is there a way to apply a count on the code so it knows when to extract one of the original number set? I have managed to do this by just repeating the code with the integer manually set less by one each time. As right now the icon stops once it has finished the first perimeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method that takes the number of moves as an argument:

```
public void moveNTimes(YourObject main, int numberOfMoves) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfMoves; i++) {
        main.move();
    }
}
```

And call that method as many times as you require without duplicating the code:

```
for (int i = 19; i >=0; i--) {
    moveNTimes(main, i);
}
```

OR

you could add a `moveNTimes(int numberOfMoves)` method to your main object.

Note:

- you can declare a variable inside a for loop
- `i = i + 1` can be written `i++`

**EDIT**

Your description is not very clear, but this might be what you are asking for:

```
for (int i = 19; i >= 2; i--){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        moveNTimes(main, i);
        main.turnRight(); 
    }
}
```

This is going to move 19 times up then 19 right, 19 down, 18 left, 18 up, 18 right, 17 down etc. and should finish in the middle of the box (you might need an extra move at the end, not sure).

Comment: Looks like a good answer however wont be able to implement it for a few hours, if it works I will make sure as to mark as correct.

Comment: I was perhaps a bit too vague with my initial problem, I have implemented your code however have made edits to my question to be clearer with my problem, your code worked great for the perimeter problem but I was too vague.

Comment: @Jambo I have edited my answer. To be honest, your new question is quite different from the original one and the original answers don't really apply any longer - that is not the way the system is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
for(int run=0 ; run<19 ; run++) {
    for(int lc1=0 ; lc1<19-run ; lc1++)
        main.move();
    main.turnRight();
}
```